# Getting data from multiple tables which has no direct connection

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have an interesting question. I need to get data from 3 tables. These tables has no direct relationship with each other. I run the below 3 queries to get the data.

```
SELECT Name FROM Student WHERE idStudent=5
SELECT Name FROM Vehicle WHERE idVehicle = 1
SELECT Marine from Soldiers WHERE idSoldier = 51
```

Now, instead of running these 3 queries, is there a way to run one query and get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT st.Name as StudentName, v.name as VehicleName, so.Marine
FROM Student st 
INNER JOIN Vehicle v ON v.idVehicle = 1
INNER JOIN Soldiers so ON so.idSoldier = 51
WHERE st.idStudent=5
```